# How calculation of std::distance works when multiple values with same value are part of the std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, std

```
    vector<int> arr;

    max = *max_element(begin(arr), end(arr));
    min = *min_element(begin(arr), end(arr));

    auto it = find(arr.begin(), arr.end(), max);
    auto it2 = find(arr.begin(), arr.end(), min);

    dis1 = distance(arr.begin(), it);
    dis2 = distance(arr.begin(), it2);
```

I wanted to find the indexes of a max and min values in the vector, so I took iterator and used distance method to compute the value.

This works for some inputs but I came across an Input where there are two min values.
`Input : 10 10 58 31 63 40 76`

So here 10 is minimum value but there are 2 `10's` but I want the distance calculated from the last occurrence of 10 not the first.

I can do this easily by holding a variable and check min values every iteration in a for a loop.

But, I would like to know if I can manipulate the `std:: distance` some way that program will take the distance from the last occurrence of 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you specifically want the 2nd occurrence, or the last occurrence? Also, why not just do `it = max_element`?

Comment: sorry didn't frame correctly, yes I want the last occurrence.

Comment: The last occurrence for min and the first for max?

Comment: I framed it as per example but the main idea is I need the program to consider the last occurrences for both max and min values

Comment: If you don't want using reverse iterators you can do:
max = *max_element(begin(arr), end(arr), std::less_equal<>());
min = *min_element(begin(arr), end(arr), std::less_equal<>());

Comment: @Equod Looks like an answer to me

Comment: @Equod I'm happy to reopen the question if it can be solved without reverse iterators, but I don't see how your solution works.

Comment: Simplify lines [3, 4, 6, 7] replacing  with "auto it = max_element(begin(arr), end(arr), std::less_equal<>());
  auto it2 = min_element(begin(arr), end(arr), std::less_equal<>());"

Comment: @cigien using std::less_equal instead of default std::less allows you to get the last max (or min) occurrence

Comment: @Equod Yes, you're right. I reopened the question, you can post an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a custom compare operator for std::max_element and for std::min_element. Using std::less_equal instead of the default std::less allows you get the last occurrence instead of first:

```
auto it = max_element(begin(arr), end(arr), std::less_equal<>());
auto it2 = min_element(begin(arr), end(arr), std::less_equal<>());
```

Example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WfjT6z)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could you please explain how less_equal works?

Comment: less_equal is just an operator (like std::less). It returns if item1<=item2 and can be written as "auto less_equal = [](auto&& item1, auto&& item2){return item1<= item2;};". The main work here is done by max_element (and std::min_element). Take a look here: https://godbolt.org/z/5b77r1

Answer (score 0):

Find the last occurrence

```
auto it = find(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend(), max);
auto it2 = find(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend(), min);
```

Using the reverse iterators should do what you want, finding the last occurrences.

```
dis1 = distance(arr.begin(), it.base())-1;
dis2 = distance(arr.begin(), it2.base())-1;
```

If I remember correctly, else test :)

Comment: Your usage of `find` will return a reverse iterator, which then can't be used with the OP's forward iterator usage of `distance` which is the question.

Comment: Yes, but the `distance` calculation is non-obvious. You might want to mention that.